# Getting pixel color from PictureBox after drawing lines

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a PictureBox loaded with a bitmap, say, a photo:

`Picture1.Image = new Bitmap("photo.bmp");`

And in `Picture1_Paint()` event, I paint a line on the photo:

`e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, pointA, pointB);`

Now, I want to display RGB info of a clicked pixel:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) Picture1.Image;  /* Making sure I'm using the image being displayed */
Color color = bitmap.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
lblSelectedColor.Text = color.R.ToString() + ", " + color.G.ToString() + ", " + color.B.ToString();
```

The problem is: the RGB value I get is the color of that pixel on the original photo, not including my line drawings. For example, if a thick red line is drawn in the sky, when I click on that red line, I still get sky-blue color from the photo.

I want to get the color info of whatever is shown in the PictureBox, including the lines or ellipses I drew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between drawing *on the screen occupied by the control* through the `Paint` event or the `OnPaint` method, and drawing on *the bitmap viewed inside the control*. You do the former but are trying to get a pixel from the latter.

Instead of drawing in the `Paint` event you have to create a `Graphics` object for your image and draw on that directly. Then assign the image to the `Image` property of the picture box.

For example, from the top of my head:

```
Image image = /* ... */;
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    g.DrawLine(myPen, pointA, pointB);
}
picture1.Image = image;
```

Then when you do `GetPixel` on the `Image` object in the picture box, you'll get the pixel value of the line you just drew.

Comment: I thought copying the Image again, `Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) Picture1.Image; ` would make sure the image includes all the drawing?

Comment: @user1032613 No, no. You have to see the difference between the image on your screen and the image in the picturebox. Any window and any control can draw on your screen. You've given your picturebox an image and it takes that image and draws that _on your screen_. When you draw something in the `Paint` event, _you are drawing on your screen_. When you do `Picture1.Image` you get the image you gave to the picturebox back from it, and that's _not_ the image that you see drawn on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Bob Powell's Eye Dropper](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811074747/http://bobpowell.net/eyedropper.aspx); here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
 

namespace pixelcolor
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for Form1.
  /// </summary>
  public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
  {
 
 
    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetPixel(
    System.IntPtr hdc,    // handle to DC
    int nXPos,  // x-coordinate of pixel
    int nYPos   // y-coordinate of pixel
    );
 
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr wnd);
 
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern void ReleaseDC(IntPtr dc);
 
 
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    private System.Timers.Timer timer1;
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;
 
    public Form1()
    {
      //
      // Required for Windows Form Designer support
      //
      InitializeComponent();
      this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw,true);
    }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
      if( disposing )
      {
        if (components != null)
        {
          components.Dispose();
        }
      }
      base.Dispose( disposing );
    }
 
    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
      this.timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
      ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.timer1)).BeginInit();
      this.SuspendLayout();
      //
      // panel1
      //
      this.panel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
      this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(216, 8);
      this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
      this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 56);
      this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
      //
      // timer1
      //
      this.timer1.Enabled = true;
      this.timer1.SynchronizingObject = this;
      this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Elapsed);
      //
      // Form1
      //
      this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
      this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
      this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 273);
      this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
      this.Name = "Form1";
      this.Text = "Form1";
      this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
      ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.timer1)).EndInit();
      this.ResumeLayout(false);
 
    }
    #endregion
 
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
 
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      Random r=new Random(1);
 
      for(int x=0;x<100;x++)
      {
        SolidBrush b=new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255),r.Next(255),r.Next(255)));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b,r.Next(this.ClientSize.Width),r.Next(this.ClientSize.Height),r.Next(100),r.Next(100));
      }
    }
 
    private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      Point p=Control.MousePosition;
      IntPtr dc=GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
      this.panel1.BackColor=ColorTranslator.FromWin32(GetPixel(dc,p.X,p.Y));
      ReleaseDC(dc);
    }
  }
}
```

If you wanted to sample the colours in a PictureBox or in your own form then you simply need to obtain the DC for that object. This can be accomplished using CreateGraphics, Graphics.GetHdc and Graphics.ReleaseHdc. The listing below shows a MouseMove handler that can be used to obtain the pixel colour from a form.

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
  Graphics g=this.CreateGraphics();
  IntPtr myDC=g.GetHdc();
  Color c=ColorTranslator.FromWin32(GetPixel(myDC,e.X,e.Y));
  g.ReleaseHdc(myDC);

  this.panel1.BackColor=c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to make a change to Jeremy's answer above to get it to work for me. The prototype for ReleaseDC seems to be different to what he posted. This worked for me:

```
    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetPixel(
        System.IntPtr hdc,    // handle to DC
          int nXPos,  // x-coordinate of pixel
          int nYPos   // y-coordinate of pixel
     );

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr wnd);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")] 
    public static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    //For best results, use a component like a Panel and use it's handle (panel1.Handle) and e.X and e.Y on a component's MouseDown event
    private Color GetColorAtPoint(Point? p = null, IntPtr? handle = null)
    {
        var hwnd = handle ?? IntPtr.Zero; // Handle;
        Point point = p ?? MousePosition;
        var dc = GetDC(hwnd);
        Color c = ColorTranslator.FromWin32(GetPixel(dc, point.X, point.Y));
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, dc);
        return c;
    }
```